# Is there a "blown save" if the closer gives up only UNearned runs?

Tags: baseball

If a closer pitches the ninth inning, coming in with a 3-2 lead, and gives up an earned run, that would characterized as a "blown save."

Suppose the run was UNearned because of a fielding error. Is it still a "blown save?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Saves and holds, like wins, are wholly dependent on the score and do not account for whether or not a run is earned or unearned.

The save rule's [first clause](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2013/official_baseball_rules.pdf) is the one clearly in play here

10.18.a

> He is the finishing pitcher in a game won by his team;

The remainder of the save rule defines the context of a save situation. If you enter the game in a save situation and fail to hold the lead then you are awarded a blown save. It does not matter whether or not the runs you allow are earned or unearned.